# How do I create real time transcript of video call?

Tags: web-applications, real-time, twilio-api, transcription, amazon-transcribe

We are using twilio video call in our application. Need to create real time transcript of that video call.

Twilio audio recording creates separate audio file for each participant and so by using AWS transcribe for transcription, it creates 2 separate transcription files. Need to have one single transcription file for whole video call.